# Styling InfoWindow Google Maps API

Tags: css, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to style the info window from my Google Maps in react.

I'm doing the following code:

```
.gm-style .gm-style-iw-d::-webkit-scrollbar-track, 
.gm-style .gm-style-iw-d::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece,
.gm-style .gm-style-iw-c,
.gm-style .gm-style-iw-t::after, .gm-style-iw-tc { 
  background-color: red;      
}
```

I'm not able to detect on the html the parts that are white and not changing to red.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was this:

```
.gm-style .gm-style-iw-d  {
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: You should avoid doing that as this is undocumented and all classnames are subject to change without prior notice. You should either use [AdvancedMarkers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advanced-markers/html-markers?hl=en#interactive_markers) or create your own using [OverlayView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-popup?hl=en).